# Removing corrupt 3Delight Renderer from Scene

Tags: mac, maya, render-settings

For a recent Maya 2018 project (Mac), I was experimenting with a bunch of different renderers. I ended up settling on vRay, but in the process I was testing 3Delight.

The problem is the 3Delight is basically a cancer now. I'm not using anything from it anymore, but I can't get rid of it from my project without it crashing. Its presence has led to several glitches and rendering problems in my project. I can't remove the 3Delight files nor unload the plugin without massive problems and crashing.

I would like to just remove 3Delight from my computer outright, but although I'm done with the project, I would like to be able to access it for various reasons.

I'm guessing I might be able to remove any dependencies through text editor, but I have no idea what yI'm doing in that and I can't find any text that goes under 3Delight's normal naming conventions.

Any ideas on how I can remove 3Delight from my file completely?

Comment: this may - or may not - help: [https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/maya-shading-lighting-and/removing-legacy-render-layers-from-scene/td-p/7868611]